# Wrong values from int array in nasm passed from C

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to pass an array of 4-byte integers from C to 32-bit nasm in linux. The function call passes a pointer to the first integer and the length in an integer value in that order. The C-program reads a list of numbers from a file. I've verified that the array is populating correctly.

When I run the following code I get consistent, large values. Each value is the same as the last and none were in the original array.

The relevant nasm code is as follows:

```
_sumAndPrintList:
    push ebp
    mov  ebp, esp
    sub  esp, 16   

    push ebx
    push ecx
    push edx
    push edi
    push esi

    mov ebx, [ebp + 8] ;Pointer to start of list
    mov ecx, [ebp + 12] ;Size of list

    push ebx
    push ecx

    push header ;This is a string and prints correctly
    call printf

    add esp, 4

    pop ecx
    pop ebx

    xor edi, edi ;counter
    xor esi, esi ;running total

printLoop:

    cmp edi, ecx ;check if at end of list
    je endPrintLoop

    add esi, [ebx] ;add value in ebx to esi

    mov [value], ebx ;move value in array to value
    mov [total], esi ;put esi in total

    push ebx
    push ecx
    push edi
    push esi

    push total
    push value
    push printNums ;string that prints the value and then the total
    call printf

    add esp, 12

    pop esi
    pop edi
    pop ecx
    pop ebx

    add ebx, dword 1
    inc edi
    jmp printLoop
```

Everything prints correctly, just the values are wrong and the total is wrong. I'm fairly new to assembly, so if I've included too much or too little or you have questions, feel free to ask/let me know.

Comment: Found a solution, but not sure about why it wasn't working to begin with. Changed third from last line to add ebx, dword 4. Also got rid of total and value and just pushed dword [ebx] and esi instead. If someone could explain the problem, that would be awesome, though.

Comment: _"Changed third from last line to add ebx, dword 4 ... but not sure about why it wasn't working to begin with ... I'm trying to pass an array of 4-byte integers"_ <-- There's your answer right there. If your elements are 4 bytes each as you say, then you need to add 4 to the address to get to the next element. Note that the `dword` is unnecessary and may lead to the assembler encoding the immediate using four bytes when one would've been enough.

Comment: @Michael: to override encodings in NASM, you'd have to use `add ebx, strict dword 1`.  Just `dword` on its own is merely an operand-size specifier.  It's totally redundant and weird to put one there, but the only downside is human readability.  (Like you, I only ever put operand-size specifiers on a memory operand, because that's the thing whose size I want to set but which isn't implied by anything.  Not on the immediate.)